# How can I set a Java System Property using the Gradle comand line?

Tags: java, gradle

I want to be able to set a system property via the command line so that it can be accessed by java code. How can I achieve this functionality?

The example below fails.

**Command Line**

```
./gradlew clean test -Dfoo=bar
```

**Java Code**

```
@Test
public void shouldGetFoo(){
    String myProp = System.getProperty("foo");

    assertThat(myProp, is("bar"));
}
```

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That sets environment variables, not properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

build.gradle:

```
test {
    systemProperty "foo", System.getProperty("foo")
}
```

This is necessary because tests always run in a separate JVM. All other task types that implement `JavaForkOptions` (e.g. `JavaExec`) have the same property. For API details, consult the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

Comment: So just to clarify, -D arguments are never passed down to JVM sub-processes? Or are they passed down for some tasks, but not the test task? Thanks.

Comment: They are never passed down automatically.